# Blender 2.82 crash when rendering a specific frame in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Still learning the ins and outs of Blender, but this one has me confused. I have a simple text animation that I'm trying to render. Frame 35 renders in Eevee, but crashes every time in Cycles. Additionally, a few frames on either side of frame 35 either render completely blank or only render fragments of the geometry. I don't believe that camera clipping is the reason for this as the camera is only moving slightly. There are no particle systems or any other complex parts of this file.

Anyone have something similar happen? If I had to recreate the entire sequence from scratch in a new file I could, but I'd kinda like to know what would be causing this.

Thanks in advance to anyone for help or tips.

Comment: Hi, welcome! It is quite a rare event that a specific frame can crash a Cycles render, and it could be due to a number of possible issues, but without having your exact same setup, nobody can help you understand what could be happening, or even try to replicate. If you wish to share your file (or a test file where this also happens), try http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then edit your question and paste the provided link, that will help for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've uploaded my working file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=kmmDSVxd" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/kmmDSVxd/)

Comment: I've done some more troubleshooting and found that turning off motion blur in Cycles resolves the issue. That's not really a good solution, though, as the rest of the sequences in this project will be using it.

Comment: I can confirm that it renders with eevee but with cycles it crashes also on my machine :) using 2.82a. And also without motion blur it doesn't crash. It seems a Blender bug, and you could report it to devs I guess...see https://www.blender.org/support/

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response, m.ardito. It also seems to maybe be a Mac-only bug, because I transferred the file to my Windows machine out of curiosity and it renders fine, motion blur and all. *scratches head* In any case, I appreciate your help : )  Not sure if I should mark this question as answered or leave it open.

Comment: I'm on linux, so it may be a mac/linux bug then :) I would leave it open, in case someone finds an acceptable workaround or some setting that avoids crashing. If you report and then blender devs accept it as a bug, you could add an answer here yourself, to explain what it was, and in which version it is fixed... you choose.

Comment: Roger that. Cheers.